How to evaluate the following exponential-trigonometric Integral?
How to evaluate the following Integral? $$I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{\cos2x}\sin (x+\sin2x)}{\sin x} \, dx$$
I tried to open the sin expression but now I am stuck:
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{\cos2x}\sin (x+\sin2x)}{\sin x} \, dx \\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{\cos2x}\sin x\cos(\sin2x)+\cos x\sin(\sin2x))}{\sin x} \, dx \\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{\cos2x}(\cos(\sin2x)+\cot x\sin(\sin2x)) \, dx \\
\end{align*}

We want to solve the Integral:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{\cos2x}\sin (x+\sin2x)}{\sin x} \, dx$$
Let's solve the following Integral $I$ and recover the original later by taking $\Im\{I\}$:
\begin{align*}
I&=  \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{\cos2x}e^ {i(x+\sin2x)}}{\sin x} \, dx  \\
&=  \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{(\cos2x+i\sin2x)}e^ {ix}}{\sin x} \, dx  \\
&=  \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{e^{2ix}}e^ {ix}}{\sin x} \, dx  \\
&=  \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{e^{2ix}}e^ {ix}}{\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}} \, dx  \\
&= 2i \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{e^{2ix}}e^ {ix}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} \, dx  \\
&= 2i \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{e^{2ix}}e^ {ix}}{e^{2ix}-1} e^{ix}\, dx  \\
\end{align*}
This form closely resembles Integrating along the semicircular part of the unit circle in the following contour diagram ie. $$\int_{C_2}$$ of the function $$f(z)=\frac{2z\,e^{z^2}}{z^2-1}$$: 
Applying Residue theorem on this contour we can say that:
\begin{align*}
\oint_{\Gamma} f(z) \, dz &= 2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{Res}(f, a_k) \\
\int_{C_1} f(z) \, dz+\int_{C_2} f(z) \, dz+\int_{C_r} f(z) \, dz &= 2\pi i  \,\text{Res}(f, 1)
\end{align*}
Let's evaluate each of them individually:
\begin{align*}
\int_{C_1} f(z) \, dz &= \int_{1}^{-1} \frac{2(ix)\,e^{(ix)^2} }{(ix)^2-1}\,idx \\
&= \int_{1}^{-1} \frac{2x\,e^{-x^2} }{x^2+1}\,dx \\ &=0
\end{align*}
Above Integral becomes zero because Integrating a odd function from {-a , a } is 0.
\begin{align*}
\int_{C_r} f(z) \, dz &= \lim_{r \to 0}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2(1+re^{i\phi})\,e^{(1+re^{i\phi})^2} }{(1+re^{i\phi})^2-1}\,ire^{i\phi}d\phi \\
&= \lim_{r \to 0}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2e\,ie^{i\phi}\, \, r }{(1+re^{i\phi})^2-1}\,d\phi \\
\end{align*}
Since Its $\frac{0}{0}$ form we can apply L'hospital's rule:
\begin{align*}
&= \lim_{r \to 0}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2e\,ie^{i\phi}\, \, (1) }{2(1+re^{i\phi})e^{i\phi}}\,d\phi \\
&= ie\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,d\phi \\
&=i\pi e
\end{align*}
Now Lets calculate RHS:
\begin{align*}
2\pi i  \,\text{Res}(f, 1) &= 2\pi i  \,\lim_{z \to 1} (z-1) \times \frac{2ze^{z^2}}{z^2-1} \\
&= 2\pi i  \,\lim_{z \to 1} \frac{2ze^{z^2}}{z+1} \\
&=2\pi ie 
\end{align*}
Let's comeback to the original equation:
\begin{align*}
\int_{C_1} f(z) \, dz+\int_{C_2} f(z) \, dz+\int_{C_r} f(z) \, dz &= 2\pi i  \,\text{Res}(f, 1) \\
0+I+ i\pi e &= 2i\pi e \\
\implies I&=i\pi e
\end{align*}
The target integral is the Imaginary part of I ie . $\pi e$

An easier way is to integrate over this contour so that you would evaluate only one residue instead of two and use the theorem mentioned in the comments of your answer here. Nice work :)

Very elegant solution.

Starting form @Prince Yadav's elegant solution
$$I=  2i \int \frac{e^{e^{2ix}}e^ {ix}}{e^{2ix}-1} e^{ix}\, dx   $$
$$e^{2ix}-1=t \quad \implies   x=-\frac{1}{2} i \log (t+1)\quad \implies dx=-\frac{i}{2 (t+1)} $$ $$ I=\int \frac{e^{t+1}}{t}\,dt=e\, \text{Ei}(t)$$
Back to $x$ and the bounds, the already given result for the imaginary part..
